# How can I scroll to an area of a page with angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a web page with a grid table on it.  When showing the grid with nor row clicked the state is "home.pages" and page URL shows this:

```
http://localhost:1495/subjects/4/admin/words
```

When a user clicks on a row for word 1234 in the grid then the state is changed to "home.pages.page" with a wordId parameter of 1234 and the URL shows this:

```
http://localhost:1495/subjects/4/admin/words/1234
```

Is it possible to have the page scroll to the row having wordId of 1234 when I am using angular ui-router?

Comment: could you use regular html anchors?

Comment: @andrew.butkus - Yes I could use these but I am not sure how I could integrate these with angular-ui-router states. I am hoping to find some example that I could use as a base for what I need to do.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll perhaps set a watch on the route change, and pick up the id, then use anchor scroll to scroll to the id on the path.

Comment: Could you select the correct answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can scroll to an area of a page using [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) service, doesn't matter if you are using **angular-ui/ui-router** or **ng-route**. You only have to create a controller for your row, in this particularly case, inject the service necessary like: $scope, $stateParams, $anchorScroll, $location and declare a method to manage scroll logic, for example:
Template:

```
<div ng-controller="RowsCtrl">
    <h1>State 1</h1>
    <p>Id: {{id}}</p>
    <hr/>
    <a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>

    <div class="fixed-header">
      <a href="" ng-click="gotoRow(x)" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        Go to row {{x}}
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="row{{x}}" class="anchor" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
      Row {{x}} of 5
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Angular states config for ui-router:

```
angular
  .module('angularApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
      .state('state1', {
        url: "/state1/:id",
        templateUrl: "views/partials/state1.html",
      })
      .state('state1.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "views/partials/state1.list.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
        }
      });
  });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('angularApp')
  .controller('RowsCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams','$anchorScroll', '$location', 
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $anchorScroll, $location) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;

    $scope.gotoRow = function(x) {
      var newHash = 'row' + x;
      if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
        // set the $location.hash to `newHash` and
        // $anchorScroll will automatically scroll to it
        $location.hash('row' + x);
      } else {
        // call $anchorScroll() explicitly,
        // since $location.hash hasn't changed
        $anchorScroll();
      }
    };
  }]);
```

and it is going to work perfectly! I hope everything is clear and you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller of your words-page, you should look at the $stateParams for /words and then take action based on that.

I suggest you add the wordId as a queryParam instead of a part of the path (like `http://localhost:1495/subjects/4/admin/words?wordId=1234`)

Assuming you have something like this in your ui-router config:

```
$stateProvider.state('subjects.admin.words', {
   url: '?' + admin/words?wordId',
   …
})
```

You could do it like this

```
$scope.$watch(
  function () {
    return $stateParams.wordId;
  }, 
  function (wordId) {
    if (wordId) {
      scrollTo(wordId);
    }
  }
);

function scrollTo(line) {
  // scroll code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after: [AngularJS anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Answer (score 0):

Router:

```
 $stateProvider
   .state('home.pages', {
     url: 'pages/',
     // Template, controller,...
   });
   .state('home.pages.page', {
     url: 'page/:wordId',
     // Template, controller,...
   });
```

Controller (`home.pages.page`):

```
if ($stateParams.wordId) {
    $timeout(function () {
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = $stateParams.wordId;
    });
}
```